# Using Class Types in Generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Let's see the example here:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#using-class-types-in-generics

All I need to do is to call a static method before the instantiation, so let's modify the example as below:

```
class BeeKeeper {
    hasMask: boolean = true;
}

class ZooKeeper {
    nametag: string = "Mikle";
}

class Animal {
    static beforeInit() {
        console.log('do something here');
    };

    numLegs: number = 4;
}

class Bee extends Animal {
    static beforeInstantiate() {
        console.log('do some bee stuff here');
    };
    keeper: BeeKeeper = new BeeKeeper();
}

class Lion extends Animal {
    static beforeInstantiate() {
        console.log('do some lion stuff here');
    };
    keeper: ZooKeeper = new ZooKeeper();
}

function createInstance<A extends Animal>(c: new () => A): A {
    c.beforeInstantiate(); // TS2339: Property 'beforeInit' does not exist on type 'new () => A'.
    return new c();
}

createInstance(Lion).keeper.nametag;
createInstance(Bee).keeper.hasMask;
```

All I did was adding a `static` method to `Animal` class, and call it in `createInstance` function, right before the instantiation, and I got the following error:  `TS2339: Property 'beforeInit' does not exist on type 'new () => A'.`

How should I modify the type of `c` in order to make typescript know about the static functions?

Comment: Assuming you have a typo and static methods are same in base and derived: `c: typeof Animal & (new () => A)`

Answer (score 0):

You can make the type on `c` more specific like this:

```
c: (new () => A) & { beforeInstantiate: () => void }
```

Or like this:

```
c: { new (): A, beforeInstantiate: () => void }
```

Those types both say that `c` must be a constructor of `A`, and `c` must also have a static `beforeInstantiate` property.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCCm8DSiAO8BO0DeAoaB0AFpALKQDWAXNAEYD29I8YAdtALzQAuGArvADcuAL65coSDABajFPHRY8haKzABbeNzABzGhF4BLVjs7QARKUMVm54WIngo0AIKtD6sCBz5CBsNyGwHTwAGb0GPAAkqz%20rIEB8AAUAJQ%20KirA9LFM8AB0IPQ6SQDkACb00BD0mtxExqZEmPAlKcIqIsK%20BKx86gAy8DoQNL3qtJhmACz24pLOCPDQ8AAe3PCsZTBuHl7pftqBwRPhkTFxCeup%20xnQWTnMBUWlFVU1SxNLBnyhocTNrXahE63WgFDQmBoi3kijMrHgAHc4IgYZhUrNHFJoP1DNllmsNltXO5PN5lAcAkEQqdorFtPFDIlruTbvdqo9CsVypVqppoCBcexvr9-pFAaCQSpwQpIdBZPRUVguPCkfLFejROJQnxWMBAnjgJFEud6cB4AAeFz49abbYkrwAPiSwBoSRV0GuHAdrjSADIcNSIrSLoz1q60l7oAA3eiGMrQEQpGhWll3PInIMmtiXZJtaAAenz0AAKgBlABMAGZKwBOGgABQw9EU3AAntAShmzu5uCVoBV4DBWPRuPjDAZoHi2%20gO%207Pd6XCU8qDItw%20Bh2O7gBqREA)

By the way, your example uses `beforeInit` in Animal, but `beforeInstantiate` in the others. You'll probably want to make those the same.